# Vertical-align Field and Value in Form

Tags: html, css

What's the best practice and the most portable way for vertically aligning a field label(free text) and a form element(e.g. `<input>`) in the same `<tr>` within a form?

Do I align the base of the label and the content of the `<input>` or do I align the base of the label and the base of the `<input>` tag itself? Could you include some examples, too?

There's no specific requirement from my client, so I just want to follow the industry standard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Oded is right, there is no industry standard for that. In fact in the design area any standard is highly subjective.

There are some common patterns (at least these two I've seen frequently) of such aligning:

1). On one row, `label` left and `input` (or other element) on the right. Based on the design, it can be vice-versa. It's convinient to use `vertical-align` css rule in such case. I prefer baseline or middle vertical aligning.

2). `label` on top of the corresponding form element. In this case the simpliest is to use `display:block` on labels. Vice-versa (label lower than form element) is usually considered not user-friendly (at least I truly think so).

**Important**: dont't forget to use `for` attribute in `label` tag with corresponding `id` attribute on form element. That is in fact kinda industry standard.

Comment: 'for' attribute in the label corresponds to the 'name' attribute in the form, not 'id'.

Comment: @Jonathan, "The for attribute associates a label with another control explicitly: the value of the for attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of the associated control element. More than one LABEL may be associated with the same control by creating multiple references via the for attribute." http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-for

Answer (score 1):

There is no "industry standard".

You do what looks good in your design.

I tend to align all to "top", so it is clear what label goes with what input - for cases where I have a text area or lots of text in the label (i.e. loads of explanatory text).